# How to display Non Diagonal 2D Array elements

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am successful in displaying Diagonal Array elements, but failed to display Non Diagonal array elements I tried a lot but unsuccessful. Here is the code what I am try with I am using Turbo C++ -

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
void accept(int a[4][4],int size)
{
    cout<<"Diagonal One:";
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
if (i!=j)
                cout<<"\n"<<i <<"  "<<j<<"  "<<a[i][j];
}
void main()
{
  int a[4][4]={{5,4,3,4},{6,7,9,1},{8,0,3,7},{2,4,5,9}};
  clrscr();
  accept(a,4);
  getch();
}
```

Example : if the array content is

```
  5   4   3   4
  6   7   9   1
  8   0   3   7
  2   4   5   9
```

Output through the function should be :

4  3  6  1  8  7  4  5

Output is displaying some of the diagonal elements also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function skips all elements in the diagonal `5739` (`i != j` takes care of this), but, based on the desired output, you also wish to skip all elements in the diagonal `4902`.

To also check for the other diagonal, replace

```
if (i != j)
```

with

```
if (i != j && i != size-j-1)
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/3kHG3Z).